# JavaScript hiding plain text similar to password

Tags: javascript, html, sha

I am trying to hide/show the plain text of a hashing function, I have been able to hide the input field but i have not been able to hide/show the plain text, the webpage has a input field and under that is the text that i am typing, then there is the hashed text, i am trying to replace the plain text with bullets.

I tried hiding it by counting the number of characters in the field and then repeating the bullet that many times. but now the page does not function at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <input 
        name="show password" 
        type="checkbox" 
        checked="checked"
        onclick="toggleType();" />
    <input 
        size="80"
        input type="text"
        rows="7"
        id="edValue" 
        type="text" 
        onKeyPress="edValueKeyPress() 
        "onKeyUp="edValueKeyPress()">
    <p id="string">Original text: </p>
    <p id="lblValue">The SHA256 hash is:  </p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="sha256.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function edValueKeyPress()
    {
        var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
        var s = edValue.value;

        var lblValue = document.getElementById("lblValue");
        lblValue.innerText = "The SHA256 hash is: "+sha256_digest(s);

        var TheText = document.getElementById("string");
        TheText.innerText = "Original text: "+s;

    }

    function toggleType() {
        var obj = document.getElementById('edValue');
        if (obj.type == 'password') {
            obj.type = 'text';
        } else {
            obj.type = 'password';
            repeat();
        }
    }
    function repeat() {
        var length = this.value.length;
        var count = document.getElementById("edValue");
        String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
        return new Array(1 + n).join(this);
        var TheText = document.getElementById("string");
        TheText.innerText = "*".repeat(count);
    }





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an input type of password?

Comment: @kennebec I think they want to change the type based on if the checkbox is checked or not (from `password` to `text`).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regex:

w/ jQuery:

```
$('YOURELEMENT').html($('div').html().replace(/./g, '*'));
```

without:

```
var text = document.getElementById('YOURELEMENT').innerText;
document.getElementById('string').innerHTML = text.replace(/./g, '*')
```

Answer (score 0):

To toggle :

Html input

```
<input 
        name="show password" 
        type="checkbox" 
        checked="checked"
        onclick="toggleType();" />

<input id="password" type="password" />
```

The javascript

```
function toggleType(){
    var inputEl = document.getElementById('password');
  if(inputEl.type != "text"){
        inputEl.type = "text";
  }else{
      inputEl.type = "password";
  }
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3MRAX/1/

Comment: They already have a method to hide the password in the field, it sounds like they are wanting to hide the result of the program where it echo's the entered text back.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this, OP, but I tried :( This is as far as I got.

Javascript

```
function edValueKeyPress()
{
    var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
    var s = edValue.value;

    var lblValue = document.getElementById("lblValue");
    var hashes = s.hashCode;
    lblValue.innerHTML = "The SHA256 hash is: " + hashes;

    var text = document.getElementById("string");
    text.innerHTML = "Original text: " + s;
}

function toggleType() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('edValue');
    if (obj.type == 'password') {
        obj.type = 'text';
    } else if(obj.type == 'text'){
        obj.type = 'password';
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input 
    name="show password" 
    type="checkbox" 
    checked="checked"
    onclick="toggleType();" />
<input 
    size="80"
    type="text"
    rows="7"
    id="edValue" 
    type="text" 
    onkeyup="edValueKeyPress();">
<p id="string">Original text: </p>
<p id="lblValue">The SHA256 hash is:  </p>
```